# Integrating a function over an interval where it is undefined at some point(s).

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For example, could you integrate $f(x)= \frac 1x$ between $-1$ and $1$, even though it isn't defined at $x=0$?

Forgive me if it is a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything simple anywhere else.

Comment: integrate over open intervals (-1,0) and (0,1).  For your example both integrals diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty isn't that the function isn't defined at $x=0$. Rather, it is that the integrals $$\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac1x\;dx = \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ grow arbitrarily large
as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By a Cauchy principal value, we have
$$\text{p. v.}\int_{-a}^a\frac1x\,dx=0.$$

If you have not learned about this yet, then you can easily say that the integral diverges due to the singularity at $x=0$.